# Why "Acquire" instead of "Aquire"?

Tags: spelling, word-form

What does the "c" add to the word "aquire" when it already sounds correct meaning the verb "to gain; to possess"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because *acquire* is formed by prepending the prefix *[ad-](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ad-)* to Latin *quaerere*. Then later on, it anglicised to *acquire*.

So why the d changed to c?

It's because of a very common phenomenon called [Assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)).

The last *consonant* of certain prefixes tends to have the same place of articulation as the the first consonant of the root words.

For example, the prefix *in-* often gets assimilated to *im-, il-, ir-* etc.

- *im-* in 'impossible'.
- *il-* in 'illegal'.
- *ir-* in 'irregular' etc.

All these prefixes are the different forms of *in-*.

The same thing happened to *acquire*, *acquit* and *accept*

- ad + quire -> acquire
- ad + quitare -> acquit
- ad + capere -> accept

Compare *require* (re + quaerere), the prefix *re-* does not end with a consonant so it doesn't change.