# Irreproducible, unreproducible, non-reproducible or not reproducible, which one to use?

Tags: word-choice, negation, spelling, prefixes

I was going to add a tag for issues of my GitHub repository, to describe an issue that would not be able to be reproduced.

Here are the four versions of this word I can think of:

- Irreproducible
- Unreproducible
- Non-reproducible
- Not Reproducible

What are the difference between these words? Are they all correct? And which one is better for a tag name?

Also, is there any rule to pick the prefix for these negative forms of the word?

I know you can say 'irrational' but not '*unrational', 'unlikely' not '*non-likely', and 'impossible' not '*unpossible'.
But I don't know how to pick the correct one for other adjectives. Is there a rule or pattern for this?

(Asterisk marks illicit/ill-formed words.)

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to use something like ‘Couldn't reproduce’ instead.  Because in practice you haven't proved that an issue _can't_ be reproduced; you've merely tried and failed.  What if someone later finds a way to reproduce it?

Comment: If you want to write correct, simple, and easy-to-understand English, always use "not". Not reproducible, not likely, not possible, etc. FWIW (native British English speaker) I can see what "irreproducible" means, but I would never say or write it.

Comment: A one-off issue. But I just don't think any of these is right for this context.

Comment: The standard IT phrase to reject such issues is "Can't reproduce", or a bit more formal "Cannot reproduce"., so I'd choose one of these. From the spellings you suggest, irreproducible is the most common, as elaborated below by Void,  and as witnessed by the famous _Journal of Irreproducible Results_. But 'irreproducible' is a much stronger statement than 'cannot reproduce'.

Comment: @ErnstdeRidder The first thing I thought of when I saw this question was that journal. The journal was humorous, and part of the humor was the title itself, and part of the humor in the title was that specific word choice. I haven't seen "irreproducible" used in a non-humorous context very often. Among those familiar with it, that journal has stamped a humorous connotation on that word.

Comment: I think there's a subtle difference in meaning when you label something un- or ir- reproducible, as opposed to "not reproducible." The prefixed words to me suggest an intrinsic quality, while the two-word phrase describes a specific circumstance or situation. "We did not reproduce x" is not as definite as "x is irreproducible." But that may be attaching meaning where there really isn't any.

Comment: I would like to apologize on behalf of my language for being so dang inconsistent

Comment: I'm not writing an answer because it's not directly to the question as asked, but @ErnstdeRidder's suggestion of "cannot reproduce" is the standard phrasing in this technical context.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- & ErnstdeRidder.  Maybe where you are.  In my technical experience "Not Reproduced" or "NR" was more common

Comment: @Dragonel It appears you're in security. Perhaps the difference is between ongoing tickets and reports/audits.

Comment: `nonrepro` or `non-repro` are the tags I've seen most often used in issue databases over the past 30 years.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a hard-and-fast rule to determine which negating prefix to use; however, there's a very loose ‘guideline’<sup>1</sup> that sometimes works:

- *un-* is usually prepended (attached) to Germanic words
- *in-* (or *il-, im-, ir-*)<sup>2</sup> is usually, although not necessarily, prepended to Latin words

*Reproducible* is derived from *reproduce* which is in turn derived from [Latin *rēprōducō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/produce#English), so the negative adjective should logically be ***ir**reproducible*, though that doesn't mean ***un**reproducible* doesn't exist.

Even though the root word is Latin, it can take the Germanic prefix *un-*. (English is a very flexible language.) Both *irreproducible* and *unreproducible* coexist and mean pretty much the same thing, but according to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irreproducible%2C+unreproducible%2Cnon-reproducible&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cirreproducible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunreproducible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20reproducible%3B%2Cc0), *irreproducible* is more prevalent than *unreproducible* and *non-reproducible*.

All the options you list are equally correct and you can use whichever you prefer, although I'd say *not reproducible* rolls off the tongue quite nicely (personal opinion!). But if you need a single word for the tag, you can use both *irreproducible* and *unreproducible* interchangeably.

---

NOTES:

<sup>1. [World Wide Words](https://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-unv1.htm)</sup>

<sup>2. all those are the [assimilated forms of ***in-***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/257090/106592)</sup>

Comment: Thanks you so much! I thought there can only be one.

Comment: In this case for some reason I find _irreproducible_ quite hard to pronounce so I too would prefer not reproducible.

Comment: @mdewey - You would change the first **e** from long vowel to short vowel.   Try it.  It's much more pronounceable.  The vowel shift will occur for that very reason.  There is probably some rule that defines this but it's beyond me.

Comment: @EllieK Well, yes, "irrepressable" is a probably more common word that "unrepressable" ("repress" has a short e) but mispronouncing a word by changing a vowel doesn't make your speech easier to understand.

Comment: @alephzero - I find both pronunciations when I search the word.  Oddly, the dictionary entry either provides one or the other but never both.  Is it a British pronunciation?  I have no idea what point you are trying to make with the word *irrepressible* but don't let that stop you.  Were you thinking *irreparable*?

Comment: @EllieK in fact I think my first _e_ is more like a schwa (as are so many of my vowels) so I am perhaps not the most helpful guide to pronunciation.

Answer (score 3):

*Unreproducible* or *not reproducible*. Note the corrected spelling.

Comment: 'Irreproducible' is also attested and equally correct.

Comment: Correct, but I think unlikely in context.